# Unable to mutate an iterated string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to mutate a string of bits with a loop (see code below) however, the input and output are the same.

```
    bitstring = "100111001101010101010101"
    print("old genome :  " + bitstring)
    for bit in bitstring:

        if random.random() < 1:
            print("old bit :  " + bit)
            bit = flipBit(bit)
            print("new bit :  " + bit)


    bitstring= "".join(bitstring)
    print("new genome :  " + bitstring)
```

this gives me the output

```
old genome = 100111001101010101010101
new genome = 100111001101010101010101
```

I have checked (with the print statements in the code) that the flipBit() function works. and it seams to be working... however, the input bitstring and the output are the same.

---

What I want to do is turn down the probability e.g.

```
if random.random() < 0.05:
```

so that only a few of the bits are mutated.

Comment: Where do you initialize newGenome?

Comment: sorry, I copied in old var names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the deleted answer, here is a working implementation:

```
import random

bitstring = "100111001101010101010101"
print("old genome :  " + bitstring)
newGenome="".join(["10"[int(bit)] if random.random() < 0.05 else bit for bit in bitstring])
print("new genome :  " + newGenome)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, strings are *immutable*, which means you cannot do the following:

```
>> hello = "hello"
>>> for letter in hello:
    letter = 'a'


>>> hello
'hello'
```

In the above example, `letter` is simply a new identifier assigned to the value of the letter in the current iteration of the word `hello`. So you can do whatever you want with that identifier, it doesn't mean it will change `hello`.

You need to turn your string into a list before trying to join it, i.e.

```
>>> new_word = []
>>> for letter in hello:
    if letter == 'h':
        new_word.append('a')
    else:
        new_word.append(letter)


>>> print ''.join(new_word)
aello
```

Comment: Your first sentence suggests strings aren't iterables, but they are. That's a different concept to being mutable.

Comment: @Kylotan sorry meant iterator not iterable

Comment: It's irrelevant that the string hello is immutable, the same (i.e. nothing) would to `hello` if it were defined as `hello = list("hello")`. The second and following sentence is correct though.

Comment: @UweKleine-Konig if you used `hello = list("hello")` you could use `enumerate` to modify it as it would be mutable. You cant do that when you use enumerate on a string (as it doesn't support item assignment). In this case I believe it is relevant that its immutable

Comment: @C.B. yeah, strings being immutable is another problem the person asking the question will hit. What I wanted to say is that the strings are not the same because strings cannot be changed, but because it wasn't even tried to change the string. (In with case a TypeError would have been raised.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for bit in bitstring:

    if random.random() < 1:
        print("old bit :  " + bit)
        bit = flipBit(bit)
        print("new bit :  " + bit)
```

when you do:

```
bit = flipBit(bit)
```

you are not change the bit in `bitstring` instead you are naming another value (that returned by `flipBit`) as `bit`.

Try this:

```
muted_bitstring = ""
for index, bit in enumerate(bitstring.spli()):

    if random.random() < 1:
        muted_bitstring += = flipBit(bit)

bitstring = muted_bitstring
```